# How to get data from 'eav_attribute_option_value' table in magento

Tags: magento, attributes, entity-attribute-value

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.0.

I want to add a custom column "Date" (Current date) for dropdown attribute value.

So, I added a column "Date"(Current date) in "eav_attribute_option_value" table.

But I could not retrieve its value.

Please suggest me.

[attribute option values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybYrE.jpg)

Comment: This is the last thing you should do - don't touch the EAV tables unless you 100% understand how they work. If you want to add an option value, you should find the attribute that it belongs to in the admin panel and add it from the "Options" tab. If you want to add a new attribute completely, do that.

Comment: In fact - I just looked at your screenshot. Doing that will not be modular like the rest of Magento - you'll find it very difficult, and suggesting how to do it would probably fall into "too broad" on Stackoverflow. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following codes to solve your query.

Below is the retrieve code for specific row value:

```
$attributeCode = 'test_dropdown';
$attributeAdminValue = 'first';

$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
    ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
    ->setStoreFilter(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
    ->addFieldToFilter('tdv.value', $attributeAdminValue);
    $value=$collection->getData(); //// echo '<pre>'; print_r($collection->getData());
```

here you can decomment this part can see option name and you can retrieve which option value as you want.

```
$value=$value[0];
echo $value['value'];
```

Below is the retrieve code for all row value of date_time

```
$attributeCode = 'test_dropdown';
Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
    ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
    ->setStoreFilter(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    if($collection->getSize()>0){
        foreach($collection as $item){
            $value=$item->getData(); 
            // echo '<pre>'; print_r($item->getData());  Here you can decomment. This part can see option name and you can retrieve whichever option value you want.
            echo $value['value'];
        }
    }
```